# Car auto-populate listing with full specification on selection of Brand and Model

Tags: php, web-services, drupal, drupal-7

Please go through the scenario, which actually explain my requirement:

I need to develop a functionality in which, when I SELECT a vehicle's Brand name from a select list, a Select list containing all the models under that brand should be populated.

After that, Once I select the vehicle model, I should get a tabular format or any appearance format, that's not matter much what I need to display is, full specification of that vehicle model with comparison with in its variants should display.

Let's have an Example:

- Select List(Brand Name)

  - Maruti Suzuki
  - Audi
  - BMW
  - Hyundai
  - Skoda
  - Chevrolet  and so on.......

When I select a brand name, lets suppose I have selected "**Skoda**", then a new select list should populate with all the vehicle models under "**Skoda**" brand.

- Select Model

  - Rapid
  - Octavia
  - Superb
  - Yeti

When I select a model, lets say "**Superb**", the full specification of model "**Superb**" with all its variants should display.

**Note**: I can develop it by making my own module or using Drupal cck modules but in that case I have to put all the data by my own and always when new models from different brands launched into the market, I have to manually add them into my System, which actually I do not want to do.

So I am looking for a solution either some 3rd party API or services which gives all the stuff at one place, what I need to do is, I just call the API with Brand Name and all the data comes to me in its response.

Sorry for the bad English.

If have any query or doubt related to the understanding of the requirement, Please add comment.

Suggestions are always welcome.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Basically, You need Automotive Specification Service to get information based on your selection, right.

Comment: Try this API, May be helpful, It has Vehicle API to get Specification.
http://edmunds.mashery.com/apps/register

Comment: Thanks Ashwin, I have not tried this yet but I think it would help me as per its documentation.....This is what I am looking for. 
will try and get back to you, once I succeeded. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I didn't hear about some module thaw would totally meet your needs so I would go for custom solution here. And you don't need to manually insert/change car data. If there's some feed you can make parser that will parse feed(s) and enter data. Call it from cron or something..

3rd party solutions are ok if they do exactly what you want. But sooner or later you'll have some additional request and it's much easier to add extra feature to you module than to other's.

Comment: Milan, I also thought for the same but it's really a tedious work to prepare a feed for such kind of large data as there are a lots of brands and every brand has lots of models and so on.... so if I got such a feed from somewhere that would be really helpful. But in this I also required updated feeds also as lots of models are continuously launching in markets now a days.